# "I will no longer use these tools any more." Is this sentence correct? if not why?

Tags: negation

Would you please elaborate your explanations on the reason why the following would be incorrect?

> I will no longer use these tools any more

Thanks in advance

Comment: _No longer_ and _anymore_ are similar in meaning. For that reason  one of them is redundant in this sentence. _I won't use these tools any more_ (1) or _I will no longer use these tools_ (2). In the first example you should provide negation. In the second example, _no longer_ itself is sufficient enough for formulating a negative sentence.

Comment: Your sentence sounds okay to me. :)

Comment: Consider usages such as: *"I will continue to use these tools some more"*, where your example is sorta the negative of it. Also, consider context and register as factors. For instance, compare against a rather formal usage of *"The company no longer requires your services."* In that type of formal termination notice, it might be less likely to have "any more" appended to it at the end--though, it could and it wouldn't be wrong, and some HR person might actually write it with the "any more" appended to the end. This is probably more of a style issue, with context and register also as factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence is grammatically correct, but as AmD points out in a comment above, the combination of "no longer" and "any more" (or "anymore") is redundant. Instead, you should use either of these:

> - I will no longer use these tools.
> - I will not [*or* won't] use these tools anymore.

In casual conversation, the redundancy would probably be fine; but then, the construction "I will no longer use […]" is probably a bit too formal for casual conversation anyway.

Answer (score 3):

In a negative expression, "any more" and "any longer" are two interchangeable adverbs:

> I don't live there **any more**.
>   I don't live there **any longer**.

So, your sentence is equal to this one:

> I will **no longer** use these tools **any longer**.

I thought obviously the two adverbs modifying the verb "use" seem duplicated.

Both of the following are better:

> I **will not** use these tools **any more**.
>   I will **no longer** use these tools.

Comment: I suspect that this is probably a dialectal difference, but -- "I do not care for this author any longer" sounds rather odd to me, though I can't quite put my finger on why.

Comment: @ruakh I changed it to an other example.